# remove tab chars from the string

Tags: java, string-matching

I have a problem when the string have mix between Arabic and English chars that forced me to add between then `\t` or `\u0009` but this makes another problem because when the text appear to the customer a lot of spaces "because of tab" between the words appear and the appearance not acceptable, any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Why were you forced to add the tabs? What problem was occurring before you added them?

Comment: Why do you have to add tabs? Because of different direction? Here is mixed Enghlish and Hebrew עברית text without any tabs.

Comment: @AlexR: LOL, the Hebrew for Hebrew. Brilliant.

Comment: Try to use wrappers for Arabic and English text-blocks. This wrappers can be something like <div> tags (HTML) with align="left" and align="right" attributes. Don't use tabs.

Answer (score 27):

You can remove any character/string from a string by using the [Replace function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29). This allows you to specify the string you want to replace, and the value you want to replace it with. When you want to "remove" you simple use an empty string as the replace value.

The following will remove all tab characters:

```
String result = myString.replace("\t", "")
```

Comment: it is obvious. However the root cause IMHO is that OP should not add tabs at all.

Comment: @AlexR: I agree the root cause is in need of review. But the question is quite clear in what they are asking. We should always answer the direct question, and only offer advice on alternatives where appropriate. Ultimately, it isn't our call to decide how they should design their applications